# Is It Advisable to Keep the Default Field Name for Anti-Forgery Tokens in Client-Side Code Despite Changing the Cookie Name in an ASP.NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

We have recently changed the cookie name used for Anti-Forgery Tokens in our ASP.NET application to 'customToken' using the AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName configuration. However, the client-side JavaScript code that sends the Anti-Forgery Token in AJAX requests still uses the default field name '__RequestVerificationToken'. Although the application seems to be working fine, I'm concerned about potential long-term implications, including compatibility issues, maintainability, and end-user experience. Could you please provide guidance on whether we should update the JavaScript code to match the changed cookie name and the best approach to ensure consistency and avoid future complications?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the client-side JavaScript code to use the same name as the Anti-Forgery Token cookie. You can update the JavaScript code by using the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` method in your Razor views to generate a hidden field with the correct name and value for the Anti-Forgery Token. You can then use jQuery to retrieve the value of this field and include it in your AJAX requests.

For example, you can add the following code to your Razor view:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <!-- other form fields -->
}
```

This will generate a hidden field with the name `customToken` and a value that is unique for each request. You can then use jQuery to retrieve this value and include it in your AJAX requests:

```js
var token = $('input[name="customToken"]').val();
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/your-endpoint',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        // other data fields
        customToken: token
    }
});
```

This will ensure that your client-side JavaScript code sends the Anti-Forgery Token with the correct name in AJAX requests and that it can be validated correctly on the server-side.

Comment: i did not updated code on client side ..but how my application is running fine?

Comment: there's 2 parts to this... the cookie and the hidden field.  The cookie is sent automatically... the hidden field is the only one you'd need to handle.  (by either sending the whole form, or adding the form fields individually as above...)